# How to install Vulkan on MacOS BigSur that runs on Mac Mini with M1 chip?

Tags: xcode, vulkan, macos-big-sur

I have a `Mac Mini M1` with `BigSur` os. I am trying to run a program that opens a window from `Vulkan` tutorial. I downloaded the latest version of `Vulkan` and folowed the [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_MacOS) how to set it up on `XCode`. I copied the files to a different location as sugested but when I got to the point to link the libraries I cannot find `libvulkan.1.dylib` in the location they specify and obviuosly I get an error when I run the program that the library is missing: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libvulkan.1.dylib`.
I have seen that you can install it using `sudo ./install_vulkan.py` or simply `./install_vulkan.py` from terminal but I am getting this error:

```
Copying /Users/username/VulkanSDK/macOS/lib/cmake/SPVRemapperTargets.cmake to /usr/local/lib/cmake/vulkan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./install_vulkan.py", line 141, in <module>
    main()
  File "./install_vulkan.py", line 120, in main
    os.mkdir(os.path.split(absolute_copy_files[key]["Dest"])[0])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/cmake'`.
```

I have looked for `/usr/local/lib/cmake` path but there is no `/lib` inside the `/usr/local/`.

I understand that in `BigSur` the paths are changed and I have seen where the packages are installed via `Homebrew`. I looks like the new default path is `/opt/Homebrew` if I am not mistaken. The problem I think is that `./install_vulkan.py` doesn't know about these changes from `MacOS BigSur`.

Does anyone have similar issues with the paths in the new `MacOS`?

Comment: Does the vkcube.app work from the SDK?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos that's a good question. Yes, the vkcube and vkcubepp from Applications directory are working.

Comment: I don't actually use `install_vulkan.py`, you can just copy out the files that you need to where you want them.  There are not many.  If you explore into vkcube.app directory you can see what you need to bundle for runtime.

Comment: As I said at the begining. My first try was to just copy the files afetr I open `vulkansdk-macos-1.2.162.1.dmg`. In the tutorial is saying to link `libvulkan.1.dylib` and `libvulkan.1.x.xx.dylib` from `vulkansdk/macOS/lib`. The problem is that I cannot find `libvulkan.1.dylib` at all. I have tried older versions but is the same. I looked to see if is a hidden file but it is not. I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Ummm libvulkan.1.dylib is definately in the SDK.  I'll find the path hang on.

Comment: It's under `${SDKDMG}/macOS/lib`.  Ummm, after you mount the DMG its under `/Volumes/`, inside that should be `macOS/lib`. ?

Comment: Check again, if it's not there the only thing I could think is that GateKeeper is deleting it as malware or something.

Comment: I think is the GateKeeper as I remeber I had this issue on a previous Mac, Intel based. I tried to disable it but in Terminal I get this messahe: `Class SPExecutionPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`. Now I have to figure it out how I can disable it, no matter where the implementation is. Thanks anyway for help.

Comment: Somehow I managed to disable Gatekeeper, downloaded sifferent versions of Vulkan but I still cannot find `libvulkan.1.dylib`. What I discovered is that is working if I do install Vulkan with `./install_vulkan.py` but still pointing libraries to different location. For example, without installation, the `vkconfig` from `${SDKDMG}/Applications` is complaining that it cannot find Vulkan Layers. What am I missing? Why the documentation says is working without installation? Is something different in `BigSur`? The tutorial doesn't mention anything about installation. Is good is working in the end.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the documentation staring in the 1.2.162.0 release of the VulkanSDK to explicitly state you should use sudo when running ./install_vulkan.py. This is necessary because the program needs to create the needed folders. Technically, you can get away without sudo if you've installed and are using homebrew, which also creates these folders.

Regarding the missing vulkan.1.dylib, this is a mystery from my end. It is a symbolic link to the actual library, so perhaps something has gone awry when extracting the .dmg file or copying the contents out. You can also specifically link directly to the library itself instead (libvulkan1.2.162.dylib if you are using the latest SDK) and not use the symbolic link at all.

Comment: It is a mystery for me as well the missing library, `libvulkan.1.dylib`, but as long as is working I'm not going to complain. It's not in the installation folder either. When I had the error installing it with or without `sudo`, I just created the directories that were missing, not sure why they were not there in first place, since I assume that the installation file for `Vulkan` knows the structure of MacOs, that's why I suspect this is something to do with `BigSur` and/or `M1 chip` but not proved my assumtion.